# Responsive, Cross browser compatiblity issue;My website is not responding right in chrome?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome

I have designed a blog over WordPress and later during QA I found out that it is working fine on all browsers except in chrome. In chrome when I check it at different widths via inspector element, the website is not fitting in the full width. After a research I realized that this might be because of this '-webkit-text-size-adjust' command. I didn’t found any replacement of it.

Link to my blog: http://www.travangelo.co.uk/blog/

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You.

Regards,
Waqar

Comment: Perhaps post some of the code you feel is causing the issue, that will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I am not sure the area of code that is majorly causing trouble that is why I have provided the link to my blog so that one may directl check it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, when I check your site between 1024px and 1170px i find an issue. Try to make this :

```
 .main-content {
    max-width:1170px;
    width:100%
}
```

insteed of

```
width:1170px
```

Comment: Thank you Dear, I have done the changes but still the issue is there. I think main-content is internal class, it might not be the reason of trouble. I think starting classes might be the reason of issue.

Comment: Ok, but in which size you want it full-width ?

Comment: Also if you take a look at the console, there is 3 issues with resource loading

Comment: Thank you, After solving console issues it got automatically adjusted.